# 'git push' leads to a pop-up in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Earlier when I used vscode, it used to ask to my github credentials in the terminal, but recently whenever I try to push any change to any repo I get a pop-up(pic attached) which redirects me to the browser to enter the credentials.

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue, since its working fine in my default terminal.

[image: This is the pop-up which I am getting.]

Comment: Did you log in?

Comment: yes, and everytime its asking the same thing.

Comment: maybe this may help? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues/1221

Comment: I still have to go to the browser everytime and authorize it. What is want is to enter my credentials in the terminal and not going to the browser everytime.